# Android Custom Keyboard Vertical and Horizontal Keys

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-keyboard

I wanted to create custom keyboard with some keys wider than normal, and some keys higher. Is it possible? Here's picture: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCyR4.jpg)

Comment: You can make a custom keyboard look like anything you want.  Do you have an actual question?

Comment: No, it looked confusing at first, but I managed to design keyboard I wanted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks for your answers. Maybe i wrote my question a little unclear but I wanted to know how to design keyboard looking like on picture, not how to create keyboard from the start.
It was a little confusing because at first I was using only android: keyHeight atribute which caused hiding other keys. Later I tried to use android:horizontalGap atribute with height attribute and that helped me to achive result i wanted.
Here's my code:  (got to adjust keys sizes some more)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keyWidth="8%p"
    android:keyHeight="14%p">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-3"    android:keyLabel="abc" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" android:keyHeight="30%"/>
        <Key android:codes="49"    android:keyLabel="1" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="50"    android:keyLabel="2" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="51"    android:keyLabel="3" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="52"    android:keyLabel="4" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="53"    android:keyLabel="5" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="47"    android:keyLabel="/" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" android:keyHeight="30%"/>

    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="54"    android:keyLabel="6" android:horizontalGap="8%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="55"    android:keyLabel="7" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="56"    android:keyLabel="8" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="57"    android:keyLabel="9" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
        <Key android:codes="48"    android:keyLabel="0" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1" android:keyLabel="Back" android:keyWidth="50%p" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
        <Key android:codes="-2" android:keyLabel="Next" android:keyWidth="50%p" android:horizontalGap="0.1%p"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```